# AWS Opsworks custom recipes don't see attributes

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I have a problem with AWS OpsWorks custom recipes. After moving nodes to chef 11 the attributes are not "seen" in recipes.
Example:
in file recipes/some-service.rb i got entry

```
remote_file local_file do
    source node['servicename']['https_download']
    owner node['servicename']['app_user']
    group node['servicename']['app_group']
    mode 0664
end
```

in file attributes/some-service.rb:

```
default['servicename']['https_download'] = 'https://corect.address.of.file'
default['servicename']['app_user'] = 'someuser'
default['servicename']['app_group'] = 'somegroup'
```

When I try to deploy app I get an error:

ERROR: Caught exception while compiling OpsWorks custom run list: Chef::Exceptions::InvalidRemoteFileURI - nil is not a valid `source` parameter for remote_file. `source` must be an absolute URI or an array of URIs. - /opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20131015111601_209/vendor/gems/chef-11.4.4/bin/../lib/chef/resource/remote_file.rb:67:in `validate_source'

It seems like it gets nil instead value from attributes.
What may I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Opsworks also is not seeing resources from the cookbooks that I'm using. I manually set the attribute in the recipe that it was complaining about the nil[] and that got me past that one just to turn up the resource not found issue...

I'm still digging and will post back if/when I find the answer...

EDIT:

What I believe has happened here is that there was a problem prior to my issue that kept chef-solo from loading the attribute data into the .json file that chef-solo uses to run. Once I fixed the first issue, the data was still non existent in the .json file for those attributes. Once I fixed the issue and it got past that point, the issue went away.